# adding facebook module to android studio

Tags: android, facebook, module, android-studio

hi ive been facing this issue for a while now have just updated android studio (the hardest thing i think ive ever had to do in my life) and it is finally working but adding a facebook module seems to be impossible for the IDE,

SO FAR

so far i have imported the module as an existing project
my system tree looks like this

```
-APPNAME
--.idea
--app
---build
---libs
---src
----main
-----java
-----res
--facebook
--gradle
```

my dependencies look like this in build.gradle

```
compile project(':libs:facebook')
```

and this

```
include ':app', ':libs:facebook'
```

in settings.gradle

and have tried lots of different variations on what people think the gradle build and gradle settings should be adding dependencies and such with little to no success is there an easier way/ foolproof way?

Comment: i know it is and i know who you are @Scott Barta but your solution is what gave me this error, and i have a new error too Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found. many thanks

Comment: If reading that answer doesn't help you, please be more specific about the exact problems you're having. As your question is written now, it's difficult to tell what's going wrong because you haven't described any symptoms.

Comment: @ScottBarta my error is Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: @ScottBarta my error is Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found. my facebook definately has the gradle inside it